# Drupal 7: Wysiwyg - Insert Blocks Plugin

Tags: drupal-7, ckeditor, wysiwyg

Drupal 7 + WysiWyg + CKEditor 4

I am using Insert Blocks plugin to add blocks to content via Wysiwyg. Inserting code manually (like [block:block=1]) works. But there is no Icon in Wysiwyg which I can use to get the same result.

I was wondering if anyone is aware of a plugin that can already do that? Basically, after clicking icon, blocks will be loaded in a window and when user selects a block, above code will be automatically added.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create such buttons using the [Shortcode](https://drupal.org/project/shortcode) module that creates shortcodes similar to the Wordpress functionality.

You can also try [Token Insert](https://drupal.org/project/token_insert), [Token Insert Entity](https://drupal.org/project/token_insert_entity) and [Token Filter](https://drupal.org/project/token_filter) modules that are using tokens and are doing similar job but not as buttons on the wysiwyg editor.